# FirebaseMessagingError: Request contains an invalid argument

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I try to send a notification to the client, but i keep getting this error:

```
error:  FirebaseMessagingError: Request contains an invalid argument.
    at Function.fromServerError (/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:254:16)
    at createFirebaseError (/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-errors-internal.js:35:47)
    at /node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-api-request-internal.js:79:75
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  errorInfo: {
    code: 'messaging/invalid-argument',
    message: 'Request contains an invalid argument.'
  },
  codePrefix: 'messaging'
}
```

This is the function i'm calling:

I get the token from the "fcmTokens" collection and i try to send the payload to the client having that token:

```js
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { getMessaging } from "firebase-admin/messaging";
import { app, db } from "@/lib/firestoreServer/admin";
import admin from "firebase-admin";

async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<any>) {
  try {
    const fcmDoc = await db.collection("fcmTokens").doc("uid").get();
    const { token }: any = fcmDoc.data();
    const payload = {
      token,
      notification: {
        title: "Hello",
        body: "hi there!",
      },
    };
    console.log(payload);
    admin
      .messaging(app)
      .send(payload)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("error: ", error);
      });
    return res.status(200).send({});
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(500).send({
      error,
    });
  }
}
export default handler;
```